# Backbone js fetch always invoked error func. Emergency ask ~

Tags: internet-explorer, backbone.js, fetch, func

There is a problem puzzles me several days. i'm gotta crazy~ My codes is below here~

```
// 
// Index
// ------
// Main controller for the application - orchestrates sub-views.
vpn.routers.Index = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes : {
    "/": "index"
  },

  // Initializes the workspace, binding it to <body>.
  initialize : function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'index');
  },

  //
  // Index View
  // ----------
  // The index page for the application
  //
  index : function() {

  }

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  // 
  // Wire up all the controllers when the document
  // has loaded.
  //

    vpn.app.ui.UserLogin = new vpn.view.UserLogin();
    vpn.app.ui.UserData = new vpn.view.UserData();

    vpn.app.data.Account.fetch({
        success: function(data){
//          alert(data.get('user').username)
            if(data.get("status") == "200") {
                vpn.app.data.UserData.fetch({
                    success: function() {
                        // render the container
                        vpn.app.ui.UserData.render();
                        // render the header
                        vpn.app.ui.HeaderBar.toRate();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                vpn.app.ui.UserLogin.render();
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(typeof(data));
            alert("stupid IE！in index.js");
        }
    });

    vpn.app.router.Base = new vpn.routers.Base();
    vpn.app.router.Index = new vpn.routers.Index();

    // Start the history
    Backbone.history.start();

});
```

When i run my HTML page in IE8, the model fetch always invoked the error func.
it return alert("stupid IE！in index.js") ~
But the same codes worked very well with FF, Chrome. i really really dont know why !
In the background program with Python, i return a data which datatype is JSON.
I really need a hand ! Thanks :) ~

> In the FF, the request is success ↓↓↓↓.

`{"status": "200", "user": {"username": "ser", "quota_cycle": 30, "site_password": "698d51a19d8a121ce581499d7b701668", "name": "", "creation": "2011-12-30 00:00:00", "enabled": true, "site": "http://shuen.blog.com/", "email": "dbdhpy@gmail.com", "note": null, "quota_bytes": 10737418240, "active": true, "password": null, "id": 2}}`

> And this is the JSON ↓↓↓↓.

`status "200"

user Object { username="ser", quota_cycle=30,site_password="698d51a19d8a121ce581499d7b701668", more...}`

Comment: can you post the raw network request results in to the question (pull it from FireBug or Chrome Dev Tools)?

Comment: @Derick Bailey, Hi, i've edited my problem just now.~

Comment: Use the IE dev tools to see what the response is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In your error callback, check the response

```
error: function(data, response) {
    console.log(response.responseText);
}
```

It's probably not the JSON you are expecting. My guess is something wrong with mime and your python backend send an error page or something else.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, i've edited my problem just now. It looks like that the console.log() cannot work with IE. And my code did work with FF.Thanx :P